# Azure snapshot backup stopped working

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have some Ubuntu server VM's are in Azure account. I got a warning from Azure that, Snapshot backup is not working properly in one of the VM.  When I am checking the backup status of this particular server, IT says that

*Backup pre-checks for this item point to issues that may lead to backup failures. Click here to resolve them*

This is the version of Agent installed in this server.

```
root@nosqlcassandrastature:~# waagent --version
WALinuxAgent-2.2.17 running on ubuntu 16.04
Python: 3.5.2
Goal state agent: 2.2.20
```

Comment: VM agent is unable to communicate with the Azure Backup Service. - Ensure the VM has network connectivity and the VM agent is latest and running. For more information, please refer tohttp://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=800034 
 Ensure that VM has network access. For snapshot to succeed, either whitelist Azure datacenter IP ranges or set up a proxy server for network access. For more details, refer tohttp://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=800034 . If you are already using proxy server, make sure that proxy server settings are configured correctly

Comment: VM is having network connectivity, I can able to ping any of the public IP from this Ubuntu server.Also able to telnet WireServer end pont from this server.I am using Ubuntu server so I dont this SElinux case is not applicable.